# dynamically change underlay colour in react native

Tags: react-native

I have some buttons but I want to change the overlay colour of the buttons after a certain time period.

When the class loads i create the buttons in an array.

```
 makeData(){
for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++){
var temparraybuttons = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

 temparraybuttons.push(<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.clicked.bind(this, (j*7)+i+1)}
                    style style={styles.circle}
                    underlayColor="#FF00FF">
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.number}>
                                {(j*7)+i+1}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>);
                }
                arrayButtons.push(temparraybuttons);
            }
        }
```

But now once they are made at a later point i want to loop through the array and change all the underlay colours is that possible?

Comment: I'd recommend states if you know how many buttons you are having. So say you have 5 buttons. After a certain interval you want to change the underlay color of the 5 buttons, correct? Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: I have 49 buttons and after 6 have been pressed i want to change the underlay colour

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class variable for count. Get the underlayColor color from state variable. Every time user presses a button update the count variable. If count variable reached 6 update the underlayColor in state.

Comment: Do I have to make the buttons in the render method then?  Right now I am creating the buttons when the class opens, so even if I change the state variable the underlay  colours are not changing.

Comment: Sure just give me a sec, the class is a bit of a mess so want to try and size it down to the relevant parts to the question